# Weak $n$-Category

Tags: category-theory, simplicial-stuff, higher-category-theory

I'm trying to obtain an intuition for ***weak n-categories*** based on explanations from:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher_category_theory#Weak_higher_categories

https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/n-category

https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/equivalence

Remark: I'm sure that there are some other approaches to this topic but from my point of view the links above might provide a nice intuition (modulo following questions).

My attempt:

So if I visualize a $k$-morphism as a $k$-cell then can I interpret a weak n-category $W$ in following way:

When we consider the  "$k$-layer" $W_k$ (=so the $k$-morphisms of $W$) with ***$k \le n$*** of $W$ then the "weak associativity" means just that that for compatible $a,b,c \in W_k$ there exist a $k+1$ morphism $d \in W_{k+1}$(in geometrical language a $k+1$-cell ) between $(a * b)*c$ and $a*(b*c)$, right?

Futhermore two $k$-morphisms $a,b \in W_k$ are identified iff there exist $k+1$-morphism $d \in W_{k+1}$ between $a$ and $b$.

On the other hand for ***$k >n$*** all $k$-morphisms are identical (in the sense that the exist a $k+1$-morphism between them. So a morphism from "next level or layer".

Is this a correct way to understand the concept of ***equivalence*** given in https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/equivalence

Now the actual QUESTION is if what I explained above is a correct intuition behind the weak n-categories and the concept  of equivalence or is my attempt to describe my intuition misleading the essentiality of the topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the $n$th layer is a standard category. 
We can even omit layers above $n$, or say they all contain only the identity cells.

What you wrote rather fits for (weak) $n$-*groupoids* (such as the fundamental groupoids of a topological space), where all cells are *invertible*.

In general, two $(n-1)$-cells $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are equivalent ($\alpha\simeq\beta$) in an $n$-category, if there is an *invertible* $n$-cell $\varphi:\alpha\to\beta$, i.e. there's also a $\psi:\beta\to\alpha$ such that $\psi\varphi=1_\alpha$ and $\varphi\psi=1_\beta$.

If $\alpha, \beta$ are $(n-2)$-cells, then we require $\simeq$ in the above equations in place of $=$. 
And so on..

To see a specific example, consider the bicategory of rings and bimodules (with bimodules ${}_AM_B$ as arrows $A\to B$, tensor product as composition, and bimodule morphisms as 2-cells).
Here two bimodules are equivalent iff they are isomorphic, and two rings are equivalent iff there are bimodules between them, which are inverses to each other w.r.t tensor product (which is called they are *Morita-equivalent*).

Associativity is required on each layer up to (equivalence on that layer). 
In the above example it's just $(M\otimes N)\otimes P\cong M\otimes (N\otimes P) $. Note that these entities are indeed not identical, for the same reason as $(A\times B)\times C\ne A\times(B\times C)$ for sets, but there's a natural *isomorphism* between them.

However, this condition for associativity in itself proved to be not sufficient, and further *coherence conditions* had to be posed, see e.g. the definition of a bicategory. 
In weak higher categories these coherence issues are highly nontrivial.

Comment: Hi, thank you a lot for explanations. Seemingly I have overseen that in general (in case of not $n$-grupoids not all $n$-cells can be expected to be intvertible so for $\alpha\simeq\beta$ in $(n-1)$ a $n$-morphism between them in general not suffice.

Comment: One aspect stays unclear to me: what do you mean by the statement that all higher layers of a $n$-category only contain identity cells? What does it mean "formally"?
In https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/n-category there is said that $(n+1)$-morphisms of a $n$-category are equivalences. By an "equivalence" is meant "invertible in a maximally weak sense". What does it mean? That there exist an $(n+2)$-isomorphism between each pair of $(n+1)$-cells? What is here the "***maximally weak*** sense"? Is that exactly that all higher cells are neccessary identity cells?

Comment: That's another approach, perhaps better suited towards $\omega$-categories, but basically equivalent: the 'identities' constraint is relaxed so that instead of requiring all $\varphi:\alpha\to\beta$ to be explicitly $1_\alpha$ (implying $\alpha=\beta$) for $k$-cells $\alpha,\beta$ with $k\ge n$, we only require $\varphi$ to be invertible (up to equivalence), implying $\alpha\simeq\beta$. In other words, from layer $n+1$ on, every cell is invertible (up to equivalence). Note that this way, equivalence goes out in the infinite, in that defining $\simeq$ on layer $k$ requires $\simeq$ of layer..

Comment: .. $k+1$, *for all $k$*. Probably this is what was called 'maximally weak sense'.